# How is $v^T(Ax-b) = -b^Tv+(A^Tv)^Tx$?

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems, transpose

This might seem a silly question but I am thoroughly confused.

Given

$c^Tx+v^T(Ax-b) = -b^Tv+(c+A^Tv)^Tx$

I get that it can be written as the second term in the RHS, but what about the first one in the RHS. Shouldn't it be $ -v^Tb $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $b,v$ are column vectors, $b^\top v$ is their dot product and so is $v^\top b$ as dot product is commutative. 
$$
b\cdot v=b^\top v=v^\top b=v\cdot b
$$